# @last element in nested each (Handlebars) C#

Tags: c#, handlebars.net

I try to dump array with objects to csv file. Each object is a row with values.

{{#unless @last}};{{/unless}} block in nested loop is interpreted as a last parent element.

There is a code for LinqPad:

```
void Main()
{
    string template = "{{#each header}}{{this}}{{#unless @last}};{{/unless}}{{/each}}\n{{#each rows}}{{#each this}}{{this}}{{#unless @last}};{{/unless}}{{/each}}\n{{/each}}\n\n\n\n\n\n";          

            var data = new
            {
                header = new string [] { "Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat" },
                rows = new item [] { new item(), new item(), new item(), new item(), new item(), new item(), new item() }

            };

    var handlebarsInstance = Handlebars.Create(new HandlebarsConfiguration {TextEncoder = new CsvEncoder()});
    Console.WriteLine(handlebarsInstance.Compile(template).Invoke(data));
}

public class CsvEncoder : ITextEncoder
{
    public string Encode(string value)
    {
        return value;
    }
}

public class item
{
    public string val1 {get; set;} = "A";
    public string val2 {get; set;} = "B";
    public string val3 {get; set;} = "C";
    public string val4 {get; set;} = "D";
    public string val5 {get; set;} = "E";
    public string val6 {get; set;} = "F";
    public string val7 {get; set;} = "G";
}
```

result is:

```
Sun;Mon;Tue;Wed;Thu;Fri;Sat
A;B;C;D;E;F;G;
A;B;C;D;E;F;G;
A;B;C;D;E;F;G;
A;B;C;D;E;F;G;
A;B;C;D;E;F;G;
A;B;C;D;E;F;G;
ABCDEFG
```

I expect this result:

```
Sun;Mon;Tue;Wed;Thu;Fri;Sat
A;B;C;D;E;F;G
A;B;C;D;E;F;G
A;B;C;D;E;F;G
A;B;C;D;E;F;G
A;B;C;D;E;F;G
A;B;C;D;E;F;G
A;B;C;D;E;F;G
```

Is this error in my handlebars template or bug in handlebars parser for .net?

Comment: developers fixed this [bug243](https://github.com/Handlebars-Net/Handlebars.Net/issues/243)